# Can't reduce extra Space in MPAndroidChart RadarChart

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I use MPAndroidChart RadarChart.

I want to reduce the space between the graph body and data description. (See figure below.)

[image: image1]

Which MPAndroidChart method should I use?

Comment: did you solve this? I have the same problem

Comment: See the same here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112855/mpandroidchart-radarchart-collapses-itself

Comment: there is the property given by the MPAndroid Chart 
leftAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f);
rightAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f);
Guess. this might help.

******for newer version******
leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
rightAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);