# MPAndroidChart RadarChart collapses itself

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, radar-chart

I have some problems with `RadarChart` labels. Specifically, if I use long texts (e.g. 15-20 chars), and the available space is not too big, the chart gets collapsed and the labels are positioned inside the collapsed chart (but there is clearly more space available).

I tried to use `ValueFormatter` for the label axis that truncates labels if they are longer than 5 chars, but as I see, the chart size calculaction is based on the full label text, as the chart got collapsed the same way I described before.

```
XAxis xAxis = radarChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setValueFormatter(new XAxisValueFormatter() {
    @Override
    public String getXValue(String original, int index, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        return original.length() > 5 ? original.substring(0, 5) + "…" : original;
    }
});
```

Here are some pictures to clarify the problem. The charts are displayed inside `CardView`s and as you can see, there is plenty of space remaining on all sides. The first two pictures are taken with the `ValueFormatter` set, the last two are without it.

[image: Description]

[image: Description]

[image: Description]

[image: Description]

Comment: did you solve that?

Comment: No, not yet; I'll try to update the lib version, there were some major updates since then.

Comment: is this issue solved with the latest library code?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are having some mistakes, here are some solutions:

1) Set your radar data after you set your `RadarChart` parameters then call `invalidate()`;

2) Set `AxisMinimum` and `AxisMaximum` in `radarChart.getXAxis()`  and `radarChart.getYAxis()`

3) Call `yAxis.calculate(min,max)` after step 2;

4) If needed use `radarChart.setExtraOffsets(?,?,?,?)`

I am using com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

```
public class MyRadarChart extends RadarChart {
public MyRadarChart(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public MyRadarChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public MyRadarChart(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void init() {
    super.init();
    setXAxisRenderer();
}

private void setXAxisRenderer(){
    this.mXAxisRenderer = new MyXAxisRendererRadarChart(mViewPortHandler,mXAxis,this);
}}
```

and

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.RadarChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.XAxisRendererRadarChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.FSize;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.MPPointF;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.Utils;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ViewPortHandler;

public class MyXAxisRendererRadarChart extends XAxisRendererRadarChart {
public MyXAxisRendererRadarChart(ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler, XAxis xAxis, RadarChart chart) {
    super(viewPortHandler, xAxis, chart);
}

@Override
protected void drawLabels(Canvas c, float pos, MPPointF anchor) {
    super.drawLabels(c, pos, anchor);
}

@Override
protected void computeSize() {

    String longest = mXAxis.getLongestLabel();
    String line[] = longest.split("\n");
    if(line .length >1){
        longest = line[0];
    }

    mAxisLabelPaint.setTypeface(mXAxis.getTypeface());
    mAxisLabelPaint.setTextSize(mXAxis.getTextSize());

    final FSize labelSize = Utils.calcTextSize(mAxisLabelPaint, longest);

    final float labelWidth = labelSize.width;
    final float labelHeight = Utils.calcTextHeight(mAxisLabelPaint, "Q");

    final FSize labelRotatedSize = Utils.getSizeOfRotatedRectangleByDegrees(
            labelWidth,
            labelHeight,
            mXAxis.getLabelRotationAngle());


    mXAxis.mLabelWidth = Math.round(labelWidth);
    mXAxis.mLabelHeight = Math.round(labelHeight);
    mXAxis.mLabelRotatedWidth = Math.round(labelRotatedSize.width);
    mXAxis.mLabelRotatedHeight = Math.round(labelRotatedSize.height);

    FSize.recycleInstance(labelRotatedSize);
    FSize.recycleInstance(labelSize);

}

@Override
protected void drawLabel(Canvas c, String formattedLabel, float x, float y, MPPointF anchor, float angleDegrees) {
    String line[] = formattedLabel.split("\n");
    if(line .length >1){
        Utils.drawXAxisValue(c, line[0], x, y, mAxisLabelPaint, anchor, angleDegrees);
        Utils.drawXAxisValue(c, line[1], x + mAxisLabelPaint.getTextSize(), y + mAxisLabelPaint.getTextSize(), mAxisLabelPaint, anchor, angleDegrees);

    }else{
        super.drawLabel(c,formattedLabel,x,y,anchor,angleDegrees);
    }

}}
```

Now replace RadarChart in your layout file with MyRadarChart
At last，setValueFormatter

```
 XAxis xAxis = radarChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {

        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            String title = "you title";
            if(title.length()>6){
                title = title.substring(0,6)+"\n"+title.substring(6,title.length());
            }
            return title;
        }
    });
```